# Vb.Net how to add an Or within an And within an If statement

Tags: vb.net

I'm normally a c# developer but currently have a VB.Net task...

This If statement is causing me an issue

```
 If Emp("Id") = 20 AndAlso (Emp("EmpType") = 2 OrElse Emp("EmpType") = 4) AndAlso IsDBNUll(Emp("Left")) = True Then
```

So I have someone dropping into this `If` statement who's

- Id = 20
- EmpType = 2
- Left = true

Because their `Left` is not null in the db, I don't expect them to satisfy this `If` statement, but they are.

I think its to do with the parenthesis round the AndAlso, but cant work it out.

What have I got wrong here?

Comment: You have mixed `dr_Emp()` and `Emp()` - is this intentional or you have left something out? Using your specified values (not database fields) I get result as `False`. What result you see for `IsDBNull()` function?

Comment: `EmpType=2` or `EmpType=4` are allowed. But in general you should set `Option Strict` to ON to avoid this type mess and implicit/magic conversions.

Comment: @Arvo Sorry that was a mistake - ignore

Comment: I'd consider restructuring this - make it more readable. Try nested If, so you can at least debug it.

Comment: I just tested your code as is and it worked exactly as you intend. Either something on your system is broken or you are mistaken about the data.

Comment: I would make two changes to that code to make it "more correct".  Firstly, turn `Option Strict On` in your project properties and also in the IDE options, so it will be `On` by default in future projects. VB will behave more like C# after that with regards to strict typing. You should also not call that `IsDBNull` function but, just as you'd do in C#, call `IsNull` on your `DataRow` or `IsDBNull` on your data reader: `CInt(Emp("Id")) = 20 AndAlso (CInt(Emp("EmpType")) = 2 OrElse CInt(Emp("EmpType")) = 4) AndAlso Emp.IsNull("Left")`. Note, no reason to compare a `Boolean` to a `Boolean` either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me rewrite condition for easier analysis:

```
If Emp("Id") = 20 AndAlso (
       Emp("EmpType") = 2 OrElse 
       Emp("EmpType") = 4
   ) AndAlso 
   IsDBNUll(Emp("Left")) = True Then
```

You have short-circuiting operators here, which might not evalute second expression:

1. in `OrElse` if first condition is satisfied, second expression isn't evaluated.
2. in `AndAlso` if first condition is not satisfied, second expression isn't evaluated.

If `Left` is not null in db, then `IsDBNUll(Emp("Left")) = True` will evaluate to `False` and whole condition will fail. There's no other way.
It might not even be executed if one of previous conditions fails.

So you have some other issue than you suspect.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is because it is evaluating as the following:

```
If 
    (Emp("Id") = 20 AndAlso (Emp("EmpType") = 2)
OrElse 
    (Emp("EmpType") = 4) AndAlso IsDBNUll(Emp("Left")) = True)
Then
```

You could just add bracket around the first 3 conditions (assuming that you dont intend for the ID to have to equal 20 if the EmpType is 4):

```
If (Emp("Id") = 20 AndAlso (Emp("EmpType") = 2 OrElse Emp("EmpType") = 4)) AndAlso IsDBNUll(Emp("Left")) = True Then
```

However, I would recommend refactoring into multiple ifs to make it more readable...

```
If IsDBNUll(Emp("Left")) Then
    If (Emp("EmpType") = 4) OrElse _
       (Emp("EmpType") = 2 AndAlso Emp("Id") = 20) Then


    End if
End If
```